# Create IShellLibrary instance in PowerShell

Tags: windows, com, powershell

How do you create an `IShellLibrary` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391719(v=vs.85).aspx) instance in PowerShell? The `IShellLibrary` interface makes it possible to manage [Windows 7 libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd758096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from code.

Does the `Shell.Application` COM object implement the `IShellLibrary` interface? Is it possible to cast a shell object to an `IShellLibrary`instance in PowerShell? Below is an example on how to create a `Shell.Application` instance in PowerShell:

```
New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
```

When I try to cast the object the result is:

```
PS C:\Users\knut> [IShellLibrary](New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application)
Unable to find type [IShellLibrary]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
At line:1 char:16
+ [IShellLibrary] <<<< (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (IShellLibrary:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

Where is the `IShellLibrary` interface located? How can I import it into the PowerShell session?

Answer (score 0):

You get hold of an `IShellLibrary` by calling [`SHCreateLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378433%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), which creates an empty one. If you want the `IShellLibrary` for an existing folder, you need [`SHLoadLibraryFromParsingName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378436%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) or one of the other related functions. They're listed at the bottom of the [`IShellLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391719%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) page.

It looks like you'll need to use P/Invoke to call them from PowerShell.

*Update*

http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2009/01/19/powershell-pinvoke-walkthrough/

Comment: Can you please provide a PowerShell example on how to use P/Invoke with the IShellLibrary?